# Video playing error

Tags: android

```
07-06 06:58:25.609: I/OMXCodec(113): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] Crop rect is 800 x 440 @ (0, 0)
07-06 06:58:25.843: W/OMXCodec(113): Number of channels: (6) 

07-06 06:58:26.085: I/AudioPlayer(113): TimeInterpolator::seek(media_time=0)
07-06 06:58:26.117: I/OMXCodec(113): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] video dimensions are 896 x 480
07-06 06:58:26.117: I/OMXCodec(113): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] Crop rect is 800 x 440 @ (0, 0)
07-06 06:58:26.257: D/OpenGLRenderer(23176): Flushing caches (mode 0)
07-06 06:58:26.304: I/OMXCodec(113): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] video dimensions are 896 x 480
07-06 06:58:26.304: I/OMXCodec(113): [OMX.TI.DUCATI1.VIDEO.DECODER] Crop rect is 800 x 440 @ (16, 16)
07-06 06:58:26.312: E/OMXCodec(113): [OMX.google.aac.decoder] ERROR(0x80001001, 10)
```

I'm playing a mp4 video and suddenly I get this error. It was fine previously. Can somebody tell me what kind of error is this? The video will play for 1/10 of a second then it stops.

Comment: try to give static width and height to your videoview.make it 800*440 and than see.

Comment: Okey. Will tell you if it works.

Comment: I don't think that it has anything to do with the video since AAC (audio!!!) decoder logs the error.
It's the software decoder. Is it possible that you try to play an unsupported AAC profile (High Efficiency, Low Delay or something else?)
Please use mediainfo on the file and show us what it outputs for the audio track!

Comment: What exactly is a mediainfo? And is it possibly because the device I'm using is rooted?

Comment: http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I just did a MediaInfo on two files, one video that plays, and the other that will not. Both was identical but the only difference was the Channels. The video that plays has only 2 channels, while the other that won't play has 6 channels.

Comment: My question is, will that info matter? I'm playing my video in a tablet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to figure it out what went wrong, the problem was that the device only supports audio with 2 channels. The video with an Audio with 6 channels was the one causing this error.